# VuforiaとPhotonを使ってオンライン対戦アプリの作り方

Tags: ios, c#, unity3d

Vuforiaという画像認識のライブラリーを使ったカードゲームアプリを開発しております。

アプリ起動後にPhotonを用いて、通常通りルームを作成し入室完了しています。
『photonを制御するスクリプト↓』

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhotonController : MonoBehaviour {


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings (null);
}

void OnJoinedLobby(){
    Debug.Log ("ロビーにいます");
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
}

void OnJoinedRoom(){
    Debug.Log ("入室しました。");
}

void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed(){
    Debug.Log ("入室失敗");
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom ("RoomA");
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        GameObject mySyncObj = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Cube", new Vector3 (500f, 600f, 1520f), Quaternion.identity,0);
    }
}
}
```

「Resources」に表示させたいオブジェクトをプレハブ化してます。
しかし、実際に実機でデバッグしてみると、片方の端末には表示されているオブジェクトがもう片方では表示されておりません。↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一応、Photonがちゃんと繋がっているかテストする為にCubeで試してみると、両方の画面でCubeが確認できました。実機テストでも両方の端末でCubeが確認できました。↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

PhotonをコントロールしているスクリプトとVuforiaのスクリプトをうまく噛み合わせる必要がありますでしょうか？
また、その必要があるのであれば、そのようなコードを書くべきでしょうか？

ご教示下さい。また、この質問のご不明点がございましたら、ご指摘のほどお願い致します。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　第三者が問題を再現しやすいように、実際のコード断片など、より具体的な情報を頂くことは可能ですか？　ヘルプセンターの[「良い質問をするには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)や[「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)もご覧ください。自分の投稿は「編集」から自由に追記できます。

Comment: 一つの解決策として、オブジェクトの表示はあえて同期せずに、エフェクトのみ同期する方法を考えています。
他にも解決策がありましたらご教示下さい。